# Sonar analysis on c# assemblies / binaries

Tags: c#, assemblies, sonarqube

I am newbie to Sonar and have a query: Does Sonar work only on .NET assemblies ?

Bit of background on my current effort:
I have successfully setup Sonar for .NET solution files (c# based projects with SVN based repository and have the C# ecosystem plugins as well).

I tried setting the binary path attribute on sonar properties file, but sonar runner failed implying .sln file needs to be mentioned.

sonar.dotnet.assmemblies=

Based on documentation at 
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+an+Analysis+on+a+C%23+Solution
...it seems solution file is must to run analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a solution file is mandatory for now to run the analysis. In the next version (3.0), it'll be possible to run an analysis on C# code without having a solution file. Note that you will need the C# code as well, not only the assemblies.